# CTE Hierarchy query performance & indexing

Tags: sql-server, indexing, hierarchy, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

I am building a view that produces a hierarchy table, with the following code

```
with EmpTree

as
(
  select e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid, cast(cast(e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid as binary(4)) as varbinary(max)) as EmpHier,
  1 as EmployeeLevel

  from DM.Dim_TFS_File as e
  where e.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid is null
  union all
  select c.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid, cast(p.EmpHier + cast(c.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid as binary(4)) as varbinary(max)),
  EmployeeLevel +1 as EmployeeLevel
  from EmpTree as p
  join DM.Dim_TFS_File as c
    on c.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_FileParent_Guid = p.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
)

select DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid
     ,EmployeeLevel
     ,(SELECT 'File Name' from DM.Dim_TFS_File as pu where nullif(cast(substring(EmpHier, 1, 4) as int), 0) = pu.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid) level1
     ,(SELECT 'File Name'from DM.Dim_TFS_File as pu where nullif(cast(substring(EmpHier, 5, 4) as int), 0) = pu.DWH_Dim_TFS_File_DWH_File_Guid) level2
```

**(this goes until level 27)**

The problem is that the view this is running against has 200M rows, so this query takes forever.

The view that this is running against, does not have an index and I cannot create one since the view is not schemabond, and I can not make it cause I do not have rights to do it.

If I had an index in the parent&child column would the query perfomance improve a lot?

Secondly I read that if I add a TOP 100% and an order by on the join clauses of the CTE that performance would improve, but I am not sure on where exactly to put this and what should I sort by.

I hope I was made myself clear, I am still a rookie in T-SQL.

Thank you!!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using!

Comment: You mean that I am using sql server management studio for this ??

Comment: I'd tag sql-server.

Comment: It is there already

Comment: try using hierarchyid column type for hierarchies on SQL server.

Comment: I'm on record many times as being a fan of hierarchyid. My question for you though is: what sorts of queries are you going to be running against this data? Right now, what you have looks like a materialization of the entire hierarchy which is not usually what one is looking for.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for replying

I want to create this table, showing all levels and upload it to a tabular model that then its fed into PowerBI.

Since its a table with many rows, and creating all these levels would mean 27 calculated columns on the tabular Model, I thought it would perform better if I materialized on SQL.

The end goal of this table is to be used as a report filter.
So I will not be running queries to this data, this data will be used in a relationship to filter.